# How to make a small icon using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a small donut hold icon - green.

Here is what I tried :

```css
        .success-icon {
          border: 1px #62ae41 solid;
          border-radius: 10px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3"><span class="sucess-icon"> </span>greater than or equal to 75%</div>
```

I couldn't get it to display. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Why not use http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ , they have a bunch of icons ready to use

Comment: Just a note, you have a typo in your HTML. You have it currently as `<span class="sucess-icon">`.

Comment: Beat me to it @user65439 - Use .fa-circle-o

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank You. In term of performance, font-awesome Vs. CSS Vs. small image, which one is the best do you know ? I'm just curious.

Comment: @saadq : Good called, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a `<span>` is `display: inline` and so `height` and `width` do not apply to it.

Set `display: inline-block` or some other value to which those properties apply.

You also need to make sure you spell your class names consistently or the selector will not match.

```css
        .success-icon {
          border: 1px #62ae41 solid;
          border-radius: 10px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3"><span class="success-icon"> </span>greater than or equal to 75%</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use display:inline-block in the style

```
.success-icon {
    border:1px #62ae41 solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some extra styles to match it to what you were kinda wanting.

```css
.success-icon {
    border: 8px #62ae41 solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-lg-3{
      vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3"><span class="success-icon"></span>greater than or equal to 75%</div>
```